# Problem Regarding Updating Values using Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is the input fields

```
<?php while($educationalQualificationsFromDB = Database::fetchData($queryForEducationalQualifications))
                {
                    $eduQualifcationId = $educationalQualificationsFromDB['education_qualification_id']; 
                    $eduQualifcation = $educationalQualificationsFromDB['edu_qualification']; 
    
                    echo "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='eduqualification[]' value='$eduQualifcation'>";
                    echo "<br>";
                } 
                
                ?>
```

This is the query I used,

```
$eduQualifications = $_POST['eduqualification'];

foreach($eduQualifications as $oneEduQualifications)
       {
            Database::query("UPDATE educational_qualification SET edu_qualification = '$oneEduQualifications'");
       }
```

I'll simply explain like this there are multiple values coming from the database from the educational qualifications table.I have used a while loop to fetch them all inside inputs.And there are several inputs right.So I need a condition to update all those relevant database data.I used foreach loop to fetch data from the inputs cause i used the name of the input fields as an array.When I update them using foreach loop it update all records with the same name.Please explain me why such thing happened and give me a solution to update all relevant multiple database values with the relevant input values.

Comment: If I get the id of the relevant input field i can use that to update the relevant field using a foreach loop.But is there any way to do that

Comment: An `UPDATE` query updates all records, unless you add a `WHERE` clause which constrains it to only specific rows.

Comment: Yeah I know that , therefore i need to get that specific id so i can update it

Comment: Yes, so you need to put the id into some form field as well.

Comment: Please ready my whole question here

Comment: Perhaps you want to transport the id as `name='eduqualification[$eduQualifcationId]'`, then you have it as key of your `$_POST` array…

Comment: Can you explain me further

Answer (score 0):

An `UPDATE` query will update *all* rows, unless constrained to specific rows by a `WHERE` clause. So you'll need to add something like:

```
UPDATE educational_qualification
   SET edu_qualification = '$oneEduQualifications'
 WHERE education_qualification_id = '$eduQualifcationId'
```

So you need to transport the `$eduQualifcationId` through the form together with the `$eduQualifcation` as well. The best way for that is to just use it as the `$_POST` array key:

```
<input type='text' name='eduqualification[$eduQualifcationId]' value='$eduQualifcation'>
```

Now your `$_POST` array will look something like:

```
array(
  'eduqualification' => array(
    '42' => '69'
  )
)
```

So you can do:

```
foreach ($_POST['eduqualification'] as $id => $qualification) {
    Database::query("UPDATE educational_qualification SET edu_qualification = '$qualification' WHERE education_qualification_id = '$id'");
}
```

As is, you appear to be open to both [SQL and HTML injection](https://kunststube.net/escapism) BTW, which you'll want to fix:

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/476)
- [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1996122/476)

*If* you have multiple users, and certain users should only be allowed to update their own data, then you'll want even more constrains and checks, something like:

```
UPDATE educational_qualification
   SET edu_qualification = '$oneEduQualifications'
 WHERE education_qualification_id = '$eduQualifcationId'
   AND user = '$current_user'
```

Because POST requests are just HTTP requests, and anyone can send any arbitrary data in an HTTP request…